# How to make wide format to be long format without using R packages in R

Tags: r

I have a data matrix below without any column and row names. Is there a way to make the data to be long format using just basic functions in R instead of R packages? Thanks!

```
response <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4)
response <- matrix(response,ncol = 2)
```

Comment: Just to be clear, can you show what output you are expecting?

Comment: Look into `stats::reshape`, which is included in base R.

Comment: @GregorThomas yes, I want the data to be c(0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4). So in the original data, each row represents one person and each column represents one variable, and I want it to be long format so that each row represents one variable for each person. If I have originally 10 rows and 4 columns, the new long format data will have 10*4 rows.

Comment: `c(response)` or `as.vector(response)`

Comment: @mhovd does reshape require column and row names for data? I checked it and it requires specifying the var and other arguments

Comment: Because typically reshaping data you want to preserve labels. And nice functions for reshaping generalize to cases where you may want to pivot only some columns, not every single value.

Comment: @GregorThomas using as.vector caused it to be c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4) instead of c(0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4)

Comment: So use `t()` to transpose your matrix first, `c(t(response))`. Or add labels so it's clear, e.g., `cbind(value = c(response), orig_col = c(col(response)))`. (Which you could throw in some `t()`s if you wanted too.)

Comment: @GregorThomas Hi thanks for the answers. I wonder if there are ways to just use matrix operation instead of the c and t operations. For example, if I have a 5X2 data matrix and I want to make the data to be 10X1 long format. Can I just use: for (i in 1:5){ for (j in 1:2) { newmatrx[ , ] = matrix[i,j] }}? Thanks!

Comment: You could make something like that work. But why would you want to? `c(response)` or `c(t(response))` is incredibly simple - something like your `for` loop would be longer to write, possibly buggy, and much less efficient.

Comment: You can also assign dimensions directly. Something like `newmatrix <- t(oldmatrix); dim(newmatrix) = c(10, 1)`. That's much better than your `for` loop efficiency-wise.